# HLA compilation problem with deprecated architecture

Tags: assembly, hla

When I am trying to compile program, a  problem show up

My steps: 

1) hlaparse -v -sg -test "p2.hla"

2) hla -v p2

```
Linking via [ld -arch i386 -o "p2" "p2.o" "/Users/( ͡° ʖ̯ ͡°)/Desktop/hla/a/hlalib.a"]
ld: warning: No version-min specified on command line
ld: warning: -macosx_version_min not specified, assuming 10.11
ld: warning: The i386 architecture is deprecated for macOS (remove from the Xcode build setting: ARCHS)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_main", referenced from:
implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
Error returned by ld = 256
```

Edit:

After:

```
hla -main:_main -l"macosx_version_min 10.9" -l"lSystem" -l"no_pie" p2.hla
```

I received:

```
ld: warning: The i386 architecture is deprecated for macOS (remove from the Xcode build setting: ARCHS)
```

Edit 2:
It's working regardless to that warning. Thanks

Comment: It looks like your command line for whatever reason is missing the actual file name, presumably `p2.asm` or similar. Could be your unconventional user name confusing hla.

Comment: I have ordinary user name. I just changed it for this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HLA (Higher Level Assembly) Installation and Linker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053784/hla-higher-level-assembly-installation-and-linker)